# PHP. Рекурсия не хочет работать

Tags: php

простая вещь, рекурсия, вот метод:

```
function check_file_due_recurs($dir)
{
    $root = 'C:/Users/Professional/PhpstormProjects/test/7-ая лаба/';

    chdir($dir);

    $all_dirs = array_slice(scandir('.'), 2);
    foreach ($all_dirs as $file) {
        if (!preg_match('/\./', $file)){
            check_file_due_recurs($file . '/');
        }
        else {
            1;
        }
    }
}
```

Прошу помощи у гуру данного языка, нужно реализовать просто бобегушки по папкам и определенные файлы сливать в другую папку, я реализовал проверки, слив, но не получается сама рекурсия, причина какова, а не очень приятная, как вы видите по вот данной строке -- `if (!preg_match('/\./', $file)){`  вместо использования id_dir() я использовал кастыль который на деле не всегда работает, но мне подошел, ибо саам is_dir почему-то наотказ я думал идёт, ибо после просмотра первой папки которая пустая оно дальше не шло.

Я решил изменить is_dir на такую простую регулярку и в итоге да, оно заработало, только поломалось дальше, поломка в строке `chdir($dir);` вот тут оно даже ошибку выдает, или как в php (я просто новичек , для вуза нужно) выдает Warning красный и дальше не работает. Я попробовал через принты поотлаживать но это результата не дало, могу лишь сказать что оно почему-то после первой папки плохо понимает что дальше обрабатывать, то есть как, у меня директории такие:
1 папка - основная, в ней 2 папки и 1 файл, файл выкидываю так как он подходит, обрабатываю папки по той же функции, первая папка обрабатывается норм, если и в ней папки то тоже норм, но только первые, дальше, то есть вторая папка она не обрабатывается.
Короче, буду благодарен совету или уже рабочему коду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекурсивный обход каталогов, нативными методами:

```
function recursive($dir)
{
    $odir = opendir($dir);
    while (($file = readdir($odir)) !== FALSE)
    {
        if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (is_dir($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file))
        {
            recursive($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'file: '.$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
        closedir($odir);
}

recursive("/home/name");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все подошло, я правда чуть позже переделал по своему, но ваш код тоже подойдёт.